# ActiveMQ Master/Slave on Weblogic - vm transport issue

Tags: weblogic, activemq-classic

I am trying to configure ActiveMQ master/slave setup on a single WebLogic machine. The problem is when I start Managed Server1 it successfully connects to vm transport and everything works perfectly, but when I start Managed Server2 I am receiving the following errors in broker logs

```
INFO  2016-September-27 10:08:00,227 ActiveMQEndpointWorker:124 - Connection attempt already in progress, ignoring connection exception
INFO  2016-September-27 10:08:01,161 TransportConnector:260 - Connector vm://localhost started
INFO  2016-September-27 10:08:30,228 TransportConnector:291 - Connector vm://localhost stopped
INFO  2016-September-27 10:08:30,229 TransportConnector:260 - Connector vm://localhost started
WARN  2016-September-27 10:08:30,228 ActiveMQManagedConnection:385 - Connection failed: javax.jms.JMSException: peer (vm://localhost#61) stopped.
WARN  2016-September-27 10:08:30,231 TransportConnection:823 - Failed to add Connection ID:ndl-wls-300.mydomain.com-52251-1474966937425-65:1 due to java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR 2016-September-27 10:08:30,233 ActiveMQEndpointWorker:183 - Failed to connect to broker [vm://localhost?create=false]: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.jms.JMSException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please help, I am stuck with this.

Comment: Too little information to go on-- what is the driving reason for putting master+slave on the same server? Would need sample code and/or other configurations to troubleshoot any further.

Comment: @MattPavlovich We are deploying Master/Slave on Same server bcoz of limitation of VM's you can say, following is broker config for ms2

Comment: <bean id="localCF" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
                  <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost?create=false" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't see the reason for the slave within the same VM. I suggest you reach out to an ActiveMQ expert consultant to validate your architecture.

However, I think I can help you move a little bit closer to this issue:

There is a fundamental miss understanding here.. the vm url is broken down like this:

vm://${brokerName}?option=value,etc

The first time you create vm://localhost?create=true.. you have created a broker

The second time you reference vm://localhost?create=false.. you have created a client connection to the first broker.

To get two brokers, you'd need two different vm://${brokerName}?create=true

Comment: Hi Matt, i have change my architecture and try two separate deployment with different ports and its working fine.. thanks

Comment: Muhammad- Glad to hear!  Would you please "accept" my answer? Thanks!